# terraform variable check for empty object

Tags: terraform-variables

I have following variable in variable.tf

```
variable "health_check_config" {
  description = "Health check onfiguration"
  type        = any
  default = {}
}
```

and this is used in main.tf code as

```
backend_service_configs = {
    default = {
      backends = [{
      health_checks = ["healthcheck"]
     } }
  health_check_configs = {
    healthcheck = var.health_check_config
  }
```

and if I define this variable in my .tfvars as below

```
health_check_config = {
  https               = { port = 443 }
  enable_logging      = true
  healthy_threshold   = 2
  timeout_sec         = 5
  unhealthy_threshold = 2
}
```

this works fine, but now I want to give this variable empty
as

```
health_check_config = {}
```

but this failed.
How I can define health_check_config empty in .tfvars or what needs to change in main.tf block to accept both empty as well as full health_check_config object

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what resource are you using. If '**health_check_config**' is a nested block then it is better to use **dynamic block**. In your case you have to modify '**main.tf**' file.

```
backend_service_configs = {
#...
  health_check_configs = var.health_check_config
}
```

and now you can make it work in tfvars:

```
health_check_config = {
  healthcheck = {
    https               = { port = 443 }
    enable_logging      = true
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    timeout_sec         = 5
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}
```

if you want to make it empty, just try to put 'null' value in .tfvars:

```
health_check_config = null
```